# CC.NET alternative trigger for waiting until another step has completed (was using intervalMultiActivityTrigger - triggerActivity)

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am using an old verison of CC.NET on a continuous build server and am using the intervalTrigger and intervalMultiActivityTrigger.  These types of triggers do not exist in recent versions of CC.NET and I am having difficulty finding a workaround in the documentation or on stackoverflow.

I have a continuous build server with 4 projects/steps.

1. Get latest code (checks every 5 minutes and continues if there is new code checked in)
2. Build database (triggers when #1 is complete)
3. Build code (triggers when #2 is complete)
4. Run unit tests (triggers when #3 is complete)

Step 1 uses a intervalMultiActivityTrigger to check if any of the other 3 projects are not "Sleeping" as to not start a second build until the rest of the steps have completed.

```
<trigger type="intervalMultiActivityTrigger" seconds="300" project="04-Do_UnitTests" projectTwo="03-Build_Code" projectThree="02-Build_Database" triggerActivity="Sleeping"/>
```

What are some alternatives to do the same functionality using the latest versions of CC.NET (check for another project activity="Sleeping")?

Comment: Can I use queue/lockqueue to do this?

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A queue will be what you are looking for. A queue can be set to contain all of your projects. The project will only be forced if it is at the head of the queue.

By default each project is in a queue with the same name aa the project. The following would force each project into the same queue, named `queue1`, with default settings.

```
<project>
 <queue>queue1</queue>
</project>
```

The queue can be configured by defining it outside of the `project` scope with the additional properties.
Your case probably does not need this, but the information is here: http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Queue_Configuration

Queues have existed since version `1.3` so as long as you are using that or a later version you should be fine.